# TYPO3 under Cloudlinux: recommended settings

Tags: typo3, cpanel, typo3-6.2.x

Our Server uses Cloudlinux on cPanel to limit resource usage per account and increase server stability. That is fine, but I have the feeling TYPO3 is throttled a little too much to do its duties.

There are several parameters that could be modified:

[docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?limits.html](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?limits.html)

Apart from the obvious CPU/SPEED parameter, what would be a recommended minimum setting for an average TYPO3 site to run smoothly?

Or are there any other experiences with TYPO3 under cloudlinux?

Comment: Please do not ask questions on multiple channels. You asked the same question on the forum/newsgoup/ML.

Comment: ok -  point taken. Sometimes I think it's different people using those channels, and when I don't get answers on SO, after a while (was too quick) I try another way to get feedback.